# Is there a grammatical construction found in one Germanic language that isn't found in other Germanic languages?

Tags: syntax, morphology, germanic-languages

If I recall correctly, Portuguese is unique among Romance languages for having infinitives that take pronoun clitics and so form equivalents to English constructions such as "for you to (do X)" or "for us to do (X)."

Are there one or more Germanic languages that each have grammatical constructions that are not found in any other Germanic language?   If so, what are some of these constructions?

Comment: That is extremely likely. Not many people here speak all Germanic languages, but take your own very English construction, for example: it doesn't work in Dutch or German. Then take the German ellipsis of the verb "have" in *wie Sie vorher geschrieben* ("as you written before"), which I believe appears mostly in literary language: it is impossible in English and Dutch. Then Dutch has the odd placement of the relative pronoun *er*: *ik heb er twee van* ("I have it two of"). Your question seems a bit open-ended: what kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: Basically the kind of answer you just gave.  You've identified two specific non-English constructions that might be unique to their respective standard languages.  This is exactly the kind of information I'm looking for.

Comment: But there are many other cases, I suppose. If another user answers the same but with different examples, how do we objectively know who best answered? Would it be possible for you to slightly narrow your question?

Comment: An exhaustive enumeration is not really plausible, but another example is *do-insertion* from English.

Comment: Well, I could narrow it to verb morphology.

Comment: More generally, it's true that each language has a set of grammatical constructions that are different from all other languages. It's part of what makes languages distinct.

Comment: why are people hating on the question? i like it.

Comment: @jlovegren It's not "hating". I think everybody likes it and I'm interested in all of the examples you could find but that's the point: The question is just too broad.

Comment: @Alenanno, I disagree with the notion that the question is too broad. Why do we have to choose one answer as objectively "the best"? We could just upvote all good answers. Please see my response to [this meta question](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/198/is-asking-for-a-list-of-languages-possessing-a-certain-feature-ok-because-its-i/201#201).

Comment: Further, I think this is the perfect forum for such questions, since once people start posting responses, people with knowledge of languages not covered in a given response can check those languages for the relevant construction and provide valuable supplemental data for that construction in comments.

Comment: @musicallinguist That's the point: [this is not a forum](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/about). I'm about to post an answer to that meta question, but if you wish, I'm in the chat. We can talk about this there, please don't reply here.

Comment: If “infinitives that take pronoun clitics” mean what I think, Spanish has it too.

Comment: The answer would seem to be 'yes' without hardly knowing any Germanic languages. I don't think it would be too extreme to say no pair of languages differ solely by vocabulary and pronunciation, however close. In English, some, mostly normal, midwestern Americans say "Do you want to come with?" That is a grammatical construction that doesn't appear in General AmE.

Comment: But the question isn't "Is there a grammatical construction that appears in at least one Germanic language but not all of them?", it's "Is there a construction that appears in ONLY one?" (the title is perhaps ambiguous, but the question text makes this clear, I think). That's a lot less trivial/more interesting.

Comment: @JPP Portuguese infinitives inflect according to the *subject*, Spanish doesn't have that. It seems to be shared with Galician and Sardinian, though. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_grammar#Infinitive_form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swiss German has a strange cross-serial semantic dependency explained here:

http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/shieber/Biblio/Papers/shieber85.pdf

This is the "We Hans the house helped paint" brought up whenever someone wished to argue that natural language is not a context free grammar. This is a silly use of this construction, but it does answer your question, because cross serial attachement is consiered ungrammatical in German German.

Answer (score 2):

Alemannic (aka Swiss German) Verb Doubling. A verb surfaces twice but is semantically computed once.

go 'go'

```
De  Hans got  go poschte
the John goes go shop
"John goes shopping"
```

afo 'begin'

```
denn fot   s   bluet afo   zirkuliere
then begin the blood begin circulate
"then the blood begins to circulate"
```

renne 'run', go 'go' 
Here, 'go' "doubles" 'renne'. My source accounts for it with generative semantics.

```
do   isch alles an d   Fänschter grennt go lose
then has  all   to the windows   run    go listen
"this is when everybody ran to the windows and listened"
```

This syntactic phenomenon, Alemannic Verb Doubling, does not exist in other Germanic varieties. Source: I'm writing my thesis on this.